# Parsing JSON array: 'paste' for bash variables?

Tags: json, bash, shell, paste

At first, I parsed an array `JSON` file with a loop using [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/), but it takes too long.

To speed things up, I thought I could return every value of `id` from every index, repeat with `word` another type, put these into variables, and finally join them together before echo-ing. I've done something similar with files using `paste`, but I get an error complaining that the input is too long.

If there is a more efficient way of doing this in `bash` without too many dependencies, let me know.

I forgot to mention that I want to have the possibility of colorizing the different parts independently (red **id**). Also, I don't store the json; it's piped:

```
 URL="http://somewebsitewithanapi.tld?foo=no&bar=yes"
 API=`curl -s "$URL"`
  id=`echo $API | jshon -a -e id -u`
word=`echo $API | jshon -a -e word -u | sed 's/bar/foo/'`

red='\e[0;31m'       blue='\e[0;34`m'  #bash colors
echo "${red}$id${x}. ${blue}$word${x}" #SOMEHOW CONCATENATED SIDE-BY-SIDE,
# PRESERVING THE ABILITY TO COLORIZE THEM INDEPENDENTLY.
```

My input (piped; not a file):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "word": "wordA"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "word": "wordB"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "word": "wordC"
  }
]
```

Tried:

```
jshon -a -e id -u :
```

That yields:

```
1
2
3
```

And:

```
jshon -a -e text -u :
```

That yields:

```
wordA
wordB
wordC
```

Expected result after joining:

```
1 wordA
2 wordB
3 wordC
4 wordD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [json](/questions/tagged/json) parser `jq`:

```
jq '.[] | "\(.id) \(.word)"' jsonfile
```

It yields:

```
"1 wordA"
"2 wordB"
"3 wordC"
```

If you want to get rid of double quotes, pipe the output to [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
jq '.[] | "\(.id) \(.word)"' jsonfile | sed -e 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'
```

That yields:

```
1 wordA
2 wordB
3 wordC
```

---

**UPDATE**: See [Martin Neal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255244/martin-neal) comment for a solution to remove quotes without an additional `sed` command.

Comment: `jq` works as expected, but I should have mentioned that by concatenating them directly (without going though `echo`), I lose the ability to colorize the sections independently.

Comment: there's also the `-r` option to jq to remove the quotes.

Comment: @MartinNeal: Thank you. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The paste solution you're thinking of is this:

```
paste <(jshon -a -e id -u < foo.json) <(jshon -a -e word -u < foo.json)
```

Of course, you're processing the file twice.
You could also use a language with a JSON library, for example ruby:

```
ruby -rjson -le '
  JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV.shift)).each {|h| print h["id"], " ", h["word"]}
' foo.json
```

```
1 wordA
2 wordB
3 wordC
```

---

```
API=$(curl -s "$URL")
# store ids and words in arrays
id=(   $(jshon -a -e id -u <<< "$API") )
word=( $(jshon -a -e word -u <<< "$API" | sed 's/bar/foo/') )

red='\e[0;31m';
blue='\e[0;34m'
x='\e[0m'

for (( i=0; i<${#id[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf "%s%s%s %s%s%s\n" "$red"  "${id[i]}"   "$x" \
                             "$blue" "${word[i]}" "$x"
done
```

Comment: Your `paste` solution is close to what I'm looking for, but what is the correct syntax for pasting together two **variables** containing the output of a series of commands (echo, jshon and sed), instead of pasting together two `jshon` outputs directly?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Birei's solution but if your output is constrained along the lines of your sample, the following may work (with GNU grep)

```
paste -d ' ' <(grep -oP '(?<=id": ).*(?=,)' file.txt) \
   <(grep -oP '(?<=word": ").*(?=",)' file.txt)
```